# Why does bash -c "false; echo $?" print 0?

Tags: bash, unix

I'm building a script that tries to run some commands on a server (over SSH), and writes on the screen whether they were successful.

I noticed a strange behaviour for `$?`, namely not being `0` when the previous command failed.

Initially, I had:

```
ssh <user>@<server> <<EOF
    false
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "It failed"
    else
        echo "It worked"
    fi
EOF
```

If I copy and paste the script inside `<<EOF` and `EOF`, it prints `It failed`. If I run it with the `ssh` part, it prints `It worked`. To simplify, I then tried:

```
ssh <user>@<server> <<EOF
    false
    echo $?
EOF
```

Same thing happened. If I copy-paste or type the commands inside, it prints `1`, but if I run all of it (including the `ssh`), it prints `0`.

The same error happens if I directly use bash this way

```
bash <<EOF
    false
    echo $?
EOF
```

or

```
bash -c "false; echo $?"
```

Why does this happen? How can I check if the previous command failed in this context?

Comment: Maybe `command || echo "it failed"` or `command && echo "it succeeded"` is helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is due to variable expansion. When you write `bash -c "false; echo $?"` the variable is expanded before the commands are ran. So your command is exactly like `bash -c "false; echo 0;"` if your previous command was successful.

To have the right result try `bash -c 'false; echo $?'`. This prevents variable expansion, it will be expanded when interpreted.

For the here document version do:

```
bash << 'EOF'
false
echo $?
'EOF'
```

In this case you need to quote the delimiter of the here document. But beware that the syntax you must use is the syntax for the shell you use to type the command. In the example, I was in `tcsh` , and it requires to use the exact same opening and closing delimiter. Under `bash`, the closing delimiter must be the opening one after quote removal.

Comment: How can he supress the early expansion in the original `ssh` setup using `EOF`?

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work for me. It still prints `0`.

Comment: I guess it is still wrong. You have to quote only the first `EOF`.

Comment: Depending on the shell you use to launch your command (I tried with `tcsh`).

Comment: Rambo is right for `bash`, you only need to quote the first `EOF`. I fixed my script! Thank you both for the help!

Comment: You explicitely called `bash` in your example and therefore you should fix it in my opinion. Additionally, `bash` is way more common.

Comment: No, I used tcsh to type the command, so `<<` is the here document is for `tcsh`, `tcsh` reads the lines and *push them* into `bash`.