# Evaluating bash variable on remote host

Tags: bash

I have a hard time evaluating variable on the remote host.

```
myCmd='echo $myVar'
myVar=test
eval $myCmd                                 # Outputs "test" 

ssh -T -p <port> <user>@<host> <<ENDSSH
  echo $myVar                               # Outputs "test"
  eval $myCmd                               # Outputs empty string
ENDSSH
```

It is a requirement that `myCmd` variable is instantiated before `myVar`. That's why single quotes are used to *freeze* string evaluation.

As the example above shows `myVar` is accessible from remote host but not used in `myCmd` evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because  `myVar` is not available in the heredoc. The variables are replaced beforehand and the echo works because it is literally `echo test`. The eval part is `eval echo $myVar` but like I said, myVar is not defined in this context and therfore it is literally `eval echo`.

Have a look at this question for some more details. [Why does bash -c "false; echo $?" print 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112579/why-does-bash-c-false-echo-print-0/31112697)

A solution could be copying the variable to the context of the heredoc.

```
myCmd='echo $myVar'
myVar=test

ssh -T -p <port> <user>@<host> <<ENDSSH
  myVar=$myVar
  eval $myCmd
ENDSSH
```

I don't know if this is suitable for you particular case but it is at least a starting point.

Another solution, and probably a better one, is to expand the expression first and then passing it to the heredoc.

```
myCmd='echo $myVar'
myVar=test
myCmd=$(eval echo $myCmd)

ssh -T -p <port> <user>@<host> <<ENDSSH
  eval $myCmd
ENDSSH
```

Comment: If there's no other solution I will go with redeclaring variable. Pity. Thank you a lot for your effort.

Comment: I found a better solution I guess. See my last edit.